# Letter permutations with restriction.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, permutations

I need help with this problem.

How many ways con you organize  P A P E L O N, so that the three vowels are not consecutive.

What I did was calculate the total number without restrictions first which is 7!. Then I tried to calculate for those which do have the 3 vowels together in order to subtract them.

To do this I realized there was 5 ways for each 3 vowel order, and each of those 5 had 4!. So 5(4!)= 5!. And then since each 3 vowel order can be arranged in 3! ways, 5!(3!).

Total would then be 7! -5!3!.

Could you tell me if its okay? Thank you very much!

Comment: So two can be consecutive but not all 3?

Comment: Yes, two of them can go together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close, but there is one problem. There are two instances of the letter P. By the generalized permutation formula, the total number of permutations of PAPELON is actually $$\frac{7!}{2}$$

And when you're counting the number of permutations where all three vowels are adjacent, the factor of $4!$ counts the number of ways to order the consonants. So once again, you must divide by 2 to account for the duplicate P:

$$\frac{5!\cdot 3!}2$$

And the difference is your final answer: $$\frac{7!-3!\cdot 5!}{2}=2160$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! I hadn't thought of the repetitions.